# How will I write php code for this code?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm struggling a little to create PHP for this HTML code. I'm more of a front end designer than back end any help? here is what  have it should be basic yet I have tried myself to get it to work seem to make it worse each time...

HTML CODE

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label></label>
        <input name="name" required placeholder="Your Name">


        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your Email">

        <label></label>
        <input name="tel" type="tel"  placeholder="Your Contact Number">

        <label></label>
        <select name="treatment">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="">Anti-Wrinkle Injections</option>
        <option value="">Dermal Fillers</option>
        <option value="">The Vampire Facelift</option>
        <option value="">Other Treatments</option>
        </select> 


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: website'; 
$to = 'email'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: {$name}\n E-Mail: {$email}\n Message:\n {$message}";


if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Thank you for your email! You will now be redirected to the Home Page.</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is it your code should actually accomplish?

Comment: You need to remove `/>` at the end of `$body`.

Comment: I planned it to be a simple form that styled myself i just do not know how to create php for it...

Answer (score 2):

This is what the PHP should be:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: website'; 
$to = 'an email address'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";?>
```

Its a ? not a / at the end

I just tested the code, using this php, and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: website'; 
$to = 'an email address'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: ".$name."<br/>E-Mail: ".$email."<br/> Message:<br/>". $message;
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. *But you missed the error too.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the braces style.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: website'; 
$to = 'an email address'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: {$name}\n E-Mail: {$email}\n Message:\n {$message}";
```

I hope you also have in mind the safety xss attacks. If not, I suggest a small tutorial like [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/).